# Error on upgrading PHP MongoDb driver from mongo v1.6.12 to mongodb v1.4

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Since mongo php driver got deprecated, I decided to upgrade my driver( On local machine of ubuntu running XAMPP stack).

To install mongodb driver, I ran following command

```
pecl install mongodb
```

I added `extension=mongodb.so` on php.ini(/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini).

But on restart lampp is was responding. So I checked the apache logs for error and I am getting this

```
[14-Mar-2016 09:19:43 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so: symbol CRYPTO_get_locking_callback, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
```

I am not getting solution for this, the only option I have rigt now is to use old mongo driver. Can someone help